# Bash Script - How to check if a package is installed and perform action based on terminal results

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, rpm

I'm currently working on a project where I need to update several systems that aren't connected to the internet. Each rpm package I have to manually download and install/upgrade the packages on each system.

I'm trying to make a script that will check if an older version of a package is installed and if it is to perform the upgrade. Otherwise, move on to the next package (I'm only upgrading package, not installing new packages.)

Here is what I have currently. The script refers to a file that has a list of all the packages. I don't have the package name for each package but I do have the rpms, so I'm curious how I can do a proper comparison in the if statement to make script perform the other action if true.

Working Solution:

```
IFS="="
while read -r name value
do

if [[ $(rpm -qi ${name//\"/}) == "package ${name//\"/} is not installed" ]] 
    then
    echo "Package ${name//\"/} is not installed, moving on..." 
else    
    if [[ "${value//\"/}" == *"kernel"* ]]
        then
        rpm -ivh ${value//\"/}
    else 
        rpm -Uvh ${value//\"/}
    fi
fi

echo 'Done!'
done < patches.conf >> patching_log.conf
```

Thank you in advance!

Input:

```
RHSA-2019:3979(kernel-tools-debuginfo)=kernel-tools-debuginfo-3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RHSA-2019:3979(kernel-tools-libs)=kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RHSA-2019:3979(perf)=perf-3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RHSA-2019:3979(perf-debuginfo)=perf-debuginfo-3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RHSA-2019:3979(python-perf)=python-perf-3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RHSA-2019:3979(python-perf-debuginfo)=python-perf-debuginfo-3.10.0-1062.7.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RHSA-2019:4024(SDL-32)=SDL-1.2.15-15.el7_7.i686.rpm
RHSA-2019:4024(SDL-64)=SDL-1.2.15-15.el7_7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Why not just setup a local mirror that they can access without internet?

Comment: That's what I would like to do but I'm new to the team and don't have the say so whether we can go that route.

Comment: just `if rpm -qi "$package"; then echo installed; else echo not installed; fi`. The `[[ $($RESULTS == "` makes no sense. And `[[$($` looks like a syntax error. Please check your scripts at shellcheck.net . The `$(...)` is a command substitution, the `[[` does something different.

Comment: rpm already has a suitable option for this exact case: `rpm {-F|--freshen} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...` - This will upgrade packages, but only ones for which an earlier version is installed.

Comment: Hey Sorin, I appreciate your comment. I didn't know about --freshen. I'm going to look into polishing up my working script tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a chance, please show us an example of your input.
I've looked at your program and I'm providing this rewrite:

```
IFS="="
while read -r patchName patchrpm
do
  RPM=${patchrpm//\"/}
  if 
    ! rpm -qi $RPM
  then
    echo "Package $RPM is not installed, moving on to next package." 
  else 
      rpm -Uvh $RPM
  fi
done < patches.conf >> patching_log.conf
```

Here's the same program again with line numbers in case you need to ask specific questions:

```
 1  IFS="="
 2  while read -r patchName patchrpm
 3  do
 4    RPM=${patchnum//\"/}
 5    if 
 6      ! rpm -qi $RPM
 7    then
 8      echo "Package $RPM is not installed, moving on to next package." 
 9    else 
10        rpm -Uvh $RPM
11    fi
12  done < patches.conf >> patching_log.conf
```

Comment: I see you added a kernel rpm check - I'll leave that up to you to add another nested if within the else clause.

Comment: Hey Mark, I appreciate your suggestion. I looked over yours I'm going to look into implementing your rewrite to make it more clean. I have ended it up getting it to work how I wanted, besides one thing. I'm going to have to have the patch name of each rpm be a simple "tcpdump", "kernel", "WhateverThePatchNameIs" etc since I was not able to find a solution to parse from the string RHSA-2019:3976(tcpdump).

Overall, I have a working method that I can polish up on my VM the next few days before we push to the live servers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a lot of logic why do not read the manual of `rpm` and use command:

```
rpm -F package_name
```

This will update it if it is installed and continue further if not.

For kernel you need to do install, not update so part of the logic should be still there

Answer (score -1):

actually you can simply do this using dpkg

```
dpkg-query -f='${Status:Want}\n\r' \-W Package
```

This will return;

0   if the requested query was successfully performed.

1   The requested query failed either fully or partially, due to no file or package being found

2   Fatal or unrecoverable error due to invalid command-line usage, or interactions with the system, such as accesses to the database, memory allocations, etc.

Comment: How does using dpkg-query, on a Fedora or a Red Hat system (as referenced in the question), help with management of rpm packages?